# Host Changed IP - What to do?

Tags: web, dns, ip, hosting, vps

My host has changed my IP address in my VPS hosting. This was a planned change they asked me when will it be good for me.

When they've changed my IP I managed to change the 2 nameserver's IP at my domain host so they will point to the new ip now.

I'm using kloxo and I have changed the DNS records for my main domain. It is working correctly with the new IP address now.

However I'm hoiting other domains there aswell but they just can't seem to be loading those sites...

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem? Maybe change their DNS to the new ip aswell? (But if I do that, won't all my domain point to the main domain?)

Comment: You can use this site: http://www.leafdns.com/ to check if those domains are pointing to the right dns, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS records for those other domains will also need to be updated. Provided that you've correctly set up your VirtualHosts (or equivalent), then changing the A-records of the other domains to match the new IP of your server shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: I have just changed the A records of the DNS to the new IP and it is just forwarding me to the main Domain :/